# inputに入力されたタイミングで該当のinputのnameを取得

Tags: javascript, jquery

現在JavaScriotの練習中となります。
以下jQueryを使用しています。

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

フォームのinputのテキストエリア内にテキストが入力されたタイミング（keyupのタイミング）で、該当のinputのnameを取得したいのですが、何か方法等はございますでしょうか。
ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示いただけますと幸いです。

```
$('input').on("keyup" , function() {
    //ここで対象のinputのnameを取得したいのですが
    //色々調べたのですが全く見つかりませんでした。。
});
```

Answer (score 2):

attribute＝”name”の値を$(this).attrで取れば良いです。

```
var attribute = $(this).attr("name");
```

Comment: ちょっとおっしゃっている意味が分からないのですが、記述の方法は以下であっていますでしょうか。

`$('input').on("keyup" , function() {`
`      var attribute = $(this).attr("name");`
`      console.log(attribute);`
`    });`

Comment: はい、そうです。
追加説明、jQuery ".on()"のコールバック内の$(this)はイベントが発生した要素をさします。
inputの"name"は、inputの"name"属性(attribute)なので、"name"属性の値を取るには、.attr(属性名)を使います。
（HTML <input> 要素"name"属性についてはこのlinkをみてください。https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-name）